# Apache redirect url containing special characters (& and ?)

Tags: apache, url, redirect, special-characters

I would redirect (or rewrite) this url:

https://example.com/image/image_gallery?uuid=233d-c888-4e&grId=125&t=15574

Into this one

https://example.com/some-sub-directory/some-sub-directory2/image.png

But i can't find how do it.
I have tried all the below redirections (separately every time) without success

In apache vhost:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)uuid=233d-c888-4e(&|$)
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)grId=125(&|$)
 RewriteRule ^some-sub-directory/some-sub-directory2/image.pngg [R=301,L]
```

```
Redirect permanent ^/image/image_gallery?uuid=233d-c888-4e&grId=125&t=15574 https://example.com/some-sub-directory/some-sub-directory2/image.png (without and with single and double quotations mark)
```

In .htacces:

```
Redirect "^image_gallery(.*)" /some-sub-directory/some-sub-directory2/image.png
```

```
RewriteRule "^/image/image_gallery?uuid=233d-c888-4e&grId=125&t=15574" "/some-sub-directory/some-sub-directory2/image.png"
```

And maybe others.

Could I have help here please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to try first and ask some issues on it.

Comment: Hi George, excuse me, when i did the post i was in hurry. I have added all my test. Thanks